# how can i loop my simple python code back to top - also filling space here because it will not take my title

Tags: python, python-3.x

If value is 1-100 it stops program
If value <1 or >100 i need to print (try again) and loop back to top.
This what i got atm

```
n1 = 0
n1 = int(input("Enter number between 1-100: "));
print ("your number is: ", n1);
while n1 > 100 or n1 < 0:
  print("Try again");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```py
while True:
    n1 = 0
    n1 = int(input("Enter number between 1-100: "));
    if n1 < 100 and n1 > 0:
        break
    else:
        continue
```

and please don't use `;` end of your code.

Comment: The initialization of `n1` is immediately overwritten, and this is an infinite loop.  See answers to previous questions for improvement.

Comment: I got it @Prune, but he didn't mention when the code exit.

Comment: His very first clause gives that:  "If value is 1-100 it stops program"

Comment: Yes you are correct @Prune, thank you for notify my mistake and I corrected it. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

This is now how python works 
First of all no need to initiate n1 and then assign input value to it 
You should have used if instead of while

```
while True :
             try :
                   n1 = int(input ())
             except :
                   print ("enter numerical value")
              if n1<1 or n1>100 : 
                    print ("try again")
              else :
                       break
Mind indentation
```

Comment: Your formatting introduces a syntax error and is hard to read.  You  removed the input prompt.  See answers to previous questions for improvement.